# Dynamically changing variable name in unix through for loop

Tags: unix, for-loop, dynamic-variables

```
Today=$(date)
for i in {2..15}
do
 week_{$i}=$(date -d "$Today +$i week")
 echo ${week_2}
done
```

I am getting no values in output in BASH.

Comment: One error easily spotted is "Today=$date" which assigns the value **of the variable "date"** to the variable named "Today". Try *Today=$(date);echo $Today* for a start.

Comment: I faintly remember that a for-loop opens a sub-shell, and any variable is local to that sub-shell and *no way* to set those values in the parent shell.

Comment: *no-way* except to place the values in a file (or a pipe??) and extract them afterwards.

Comment: @Starkeen it looks like there is a typo in your edit. Putting "Today=$date for i in {2..15} do" in one line gives a syntax error. Should be 2 lines or a ";" befor the "for".

Comment: and another newline or semicolon before the "do"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way...

```
    Today=$(date)
    for i in {2..15} 
    do
        tmp=$(date -d "$Today +$i week")
        eval week_${i}=\$tmp
        eval echo  \$week_${i}
    done
```

Second way...

```
    Today=$(date)
    for i in {2..15} 
    do
        week_[$i]=$(date -d "$Today +$i week")
        echo ${week_[$i]}
    done
```

Third way...

```
    Today=$(date)
    for i in {2..15} 
    do
        eval echo \${week_${i}:=$(date -d "$Today +$i week")} > /dev/null
    done

    for i in {2..15} 
    do
        eval echo  \$week_${i}
    done
```

Comment: Could you please explain a bit? I'm no rookie to bash, but I mostly just *used* it. Transferring variable assignments from within a loop to the outside, I could never manage, and I had some try about it. It was a while loop, but I can' believe "for" could be much different.

Comment: In this examples variables available after loop. See second loop in "Third way".